# How can i call an Geo Class from Fragment (It has cast problem)

Tags: android, fragment

[Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVcBG.png)

**Hi, i created an drawer navigation menu activity, and i have AnasayfaFragment. I want to calculate distance between 2 locations with google distance api but i cant call geo.class from fragment. I get an error. This is about casting.I get an error from GeoTask.java about public GeoTask(Context mContext) {this.mContext = mContext;geo1= (Geo) mContext;}
  :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.orderapp, PID: 25413
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.orderapp.GeoTask$Geo
        at com.example.orderapp.GeoTask.<init>(GeoTask.java:33)
        at com.example.orderapp.anasayfa.AnasayfaFragment$1.onClick(AnasayfaFragment.java:515)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7256)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7218)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27719)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25413 SIG: 9
```

And this is GeoTask.java. How can i cast?

```
package com.example.orderapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by SRIVASTAVA on 1/9/2016.
 */
/*The instance of this class is called by "MainActivty",to get the time taken reach the destination from Google Distance Matrix API in background.
  This class contains interface "Geo" to call the function setDouble(String) defined in "MainActivity.class" to display the result.*/
public class GeoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context mContext;
    Double duration;
    Geo geo1;
//constructor is used to get the context.
    public GeoTask(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        geo1= (Geo) mContext;
    }
//This function is executed before before "doInBackground(String...params)" is executed to dispaly the progress dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pd.setMessage("Loading");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }
//This function is executed after the execution of "doInBackground(String...params)" to dismiss the dispalyed progress dialog and call "setDouble(Double)" defined in "MainActivity.java"
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aDouble) {
        super.onPostExecute(aDouble);
        if(aDouble!=null)
        {
         geo1.setDouble(aDouble);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error4!Please Try Again wiht proper values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url=new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.connect();
            int statuscode=con.getResponseCode();
            if(statuscode== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                String line=br.readLine();
                while(line!=null)
                {
                    sb.append(line);
                    line=br.readLine();
                }
                String json=sb.toString();
                Log.d("JSON",json);
                JSONObject root=new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray array_rows=root.getJSONArray("rows");
                Log.d("JSON","array_rows:"+array_rows);
                JSONObject object_rows=array_rows.getJSONObject(0);
                Log.d("JSON","object_rows:"+object_rows);
                JSONArray array_elements=object_rows.getJSONArray("elements");
                Log.d("JSON","array_elements:"+array_elements);
                JSONObject object_elements=array_elements.getJSONObject(0);
                Log.d("JSON","object_elements:"+object_elements);
                JSONObject object_duration=object_elements.getJSONObject("duration");
                JSONObject object_distance=object_elements.getJSONObject("distance");

                Log.d("JSON","object_duration:"+object_duration);
                return object_duration.getString("value")+","+object_distance.getString("value");

            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("error", "error1");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("error", "error2");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("error","error3");
        }


        return null;
    }
    interface Geo{
        public void setDouble(String min);
    }

}
```

This is my AnasayfaFragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.anasayfa_fragment, container, false);
        bottom_sheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet);
        new getJsonResponseSiparisBilgileri().execute();
        new getJsonResponseTedarikciBilgi().execute();
        imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        btnonayla=view.findViewById(R.id.btnOnayla);
        txtMesafe=view.findViewById(R.id.txtMesafe);
        txtsure=view.findViewById(R.id.textSure);

        getDirection=(CircularImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.btngetdirection);
        getDirection.setOnClickListener(this);
           btnonayla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + "37.8716794,32.4915672" + "&destinations=" + "37.8716794,32.4915672" + "&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&avoid=tolls&key=myKey";
                new GeoTask(getActivity().getApplication()).execute(url);

            }
        });
```

This is AnasayfaActivity

```
package com.example.orderapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class AnasayfaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;    private Polyline currentPolyline;

    private MarkerOptions place1, place2;
    List<MarkerOptions> markerOptionsList=new ArrayList<>();
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anasayfa);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_anasayfa,R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_siparislerim, R.id.nav_grafikler,
                R.id.nav_guncelle, R.id.nav_davet, R.id.nav_help,R.id.nav_howtouse,R.id.nav_aboutus,R.id.nav_oneriSikayet,R.id.nav_kullanimKosul,R.id.nav_quit)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.anasayfa, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }






}
```

Comment: can we see  , how you initialize Geo on your fragment  ?

Comment: Of course I will edit my code again. Thank you